# PDO fetchAll and foreach not returning first row

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have this in my PHP:

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$database", $username, $password);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$selected_client = $_POST['client'];
$sql = 'SELECT `cohort_id`,`cohort_name`, `cohort_description` FROM table_cohorts where client_id = :client';
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY) );
$stmt->execute(array(':client' => $selected_client));
foreach ($stmt as $row){
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
}
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($result);
```

This returns something that's ALMOST correct. It returns all the relevant, expected rows from my db table except for the first one. I'm guessing that I'm overwriting that somehow, but not sure where it's going wrong.

Comment: Why don't you just do `$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` and get rid of the `foreach` loop?

Comment: Well, that's embarrassing. A simple fix for something I was trying to overly complicate. Post as an answer and I can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use

`$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`

and get rid of the `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 3):

Unsure of why you've got a foreach loop in there. You'd use a foreach on `$result` to loop through the rows when what you want here is all the rows so you'd drop the loop.

```
foreach ($stmt as $row){
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
}
```

and keep just this part.

```
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```